# Pandas read_excel returning 'not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-import

My problem is pretty simple, I'm just trying to read a locally located excel file into a dataframe using pandas.

```
filename = 'test.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
```

The xlsx file has multiple sheets, but I get the same **"ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"** even when specifying sheetname.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       pd.read_excel(filename)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line
>   200, in read_excel
>       io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line
>   257, in **init**
>       self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd__init__.py",
>   line 422, in open_workbook
>       ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line
>   833, in open_workbook_2007_xml
>       x12sheet.process_stream(zflo, heading)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line
>   553, in own_process_stream
>       self.do_merge_cell(elem)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line
>   609, in do_merge_cell
>       first_cell_ref, last_cell_ref = ref.split(':')
>
> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Edit: I created a new Excel file, and copied two of the tabs from the original file over to the new Excel file. Pandas read_excel worked with the new file. However, I want to be able to work from the original.

Comment: Can you post the **full** traceback please?

Comment: @FHTMitchell Added.

Comment: Thanks. That is odd. What version of python and pandas is this?

Comment: Do you have any abnormal formulas in your excel file?  It looks like its trying to evaluate a range in a formula (which typically would look like `A1:B2`) but it is failing to find the `:` character.

Comment: @FHTMitchell Python 3.6, Pandas 0.20.1

Comment: @0x5453 In some of the sheets in the workbook, the first few cells in the first row are merged together. It's all just text.

Comment: @jerbear Considering the traceback is failing in `do_merge_cell`, I would bet those merged cells are the problem.  This could be a bug in the [xlrd](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd) library; I would encourage you to throw together an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if you can reliably reproduce the error, you should submit a bug report to the maintainers of xlrd.  As a workaround, you might be able to manually unmerge those cells before reading the file.

Comment: @0x5453 I moved and copied a few of the sheets in the original file to a new file, and then ran pandas read_excel on the new file. It worked then, but I want to be able to work from the original file. It also tells me that the merged cells aren't the issue.

Comment: @jerbear Oh, interesting.  I'm not sure then; perhaps you can try saving a copy, then removing sections until it begins to work?  I think you need to narrow down exactly where the problem is in the original document, and then determine whether the problematic sections are something you can work around or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't fully understand the mechanics of this issue, but I was able to work around it. I used urlopen from urllib.requests to download the file locally, and used openpyxl to load the workbook, and then loaded the sheet I wanted. The sheet has 5 rows of merged cells at the top and 5 rows of merged cells at the bottom. I then un-merged *just the last 5 rows of merged cells* using the unmerge_cells method. I then saved the workbook again with the modified sheet. I was then able to run pd.read_excel with the skiprows=5 parameter. It worked this way.

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround could be as following:

```
import openpyxl

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('filename.xlsx') ## opening the file
sheets_list = list(wb1.get_sheet_names()) ## getting all sheets' streams
active_sheet = wb1.get_sheet_by_name(sheets_list[0]) ## picking up the first sheet

df1 = pd.DataFrame(active_sheet.values)

df1 = df1.iloc[3 : , :] ## skipping first three rows assuming merged cells are in 
                        ## this range
```